# ARM Template - Passing parameters with Powershell AND use Secret values

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template, infrastructure-as-code

I'm pretty sure I know the answer is "no" but my scenario has a combination of requirements:
I am designing an ARM template to be shared to a group of Sys Admins for deploying Win Servers to Azure.

I am wrapping a PowerShell function around it so it can be used like this

New-AzureVM -vmName "test01" -OsVersion "Server 2019" etc
This will build values and pipe that to the New-AzResourceGroupDeployment

I also need to pass in secret values for Joining the VM to the Domain and using a Local Admin account on the VM.  I believe this requires a Parameter file.

However, if using a Parameter file, I cannot seem to find a way of also passing parameters via PowerShell when using a remote repo.

I am currently testing using templates in an Azure container blob and referencing SAS tokens with -templateURI and -templateParameterURI. But you can't have a parameter file AND parameters in the main template. Is there a way of achieving this?

All I want to achieve works no problem with a local repo - so before I give up and just show the sys admins how to clone a remote repo locally with Git - thought I'd reach out to the community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I also need to pass in secret values for Joining the VM to the Domain
>   and using a Local Admin account on the VM. I believe this requires a
>   Parameter file.

why do you believe so? you can pass them with powershell, but then you have to pass all the parameters with powershell (or use defaults for those that are not passed)

> However, if using a Parameter file, I cannot seem to find a way of
>   also passing parameters via PowerShell when using a remote repo.

this one is true

so you can download the file locally, use the local file and override some parameters with powershell

Comment: you're right, I might have to download the files locally.  In the function I'll have to generate Storage Account Keys >Storage Account context > Get-AzStorageBlobContext -dest <local> and work from there. I'll give it ago!

Comment: Thanks @4c74356b41
Having the powershell function generate Storage Account Keys for Context and then stashing the template and parameters files locally to deploy worked perfectly

Answer (score 0):

I've used a key vault in the past. Store the password in the keyvault and recall it into a parameter in powershell when you need to pass it to the template.